# Error when accessing Activities for contact (after upgrade to 4.7.2)

Tags: activities, permissions, ajax

When a management user tries to open Activities tab for a contact he gets error message
[image: Error message]

Error that I see when I try to trace it:

*API permission check failed for Case/getcount call; insufficient permission: require Array*

That affects users with particular role (works fine for administrator) and appeared after upgrade to 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the same condition against a Plan copy of CiviCRM Version 4.7.2

I can View the activities without any error - so please try disabling all the installed extension first and try the same if you are still getting an error then - Try to install an Plan copy and test it again

Answer (score 0):

Check the "CiviCase: access my cases and activities" missing from "Management" role.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in earlier versions of CiviCRM 4.7.  See [CRM-18456](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18456).  The solution is to upgrade to CiviCRM 4.7.7 or later.